# Rails: saving a record with a many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I found an excellent example of setting up a many-to-many relationship in a Rails app [here](http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/). The example lets Users be created and associated with Groups via a linking Membership table. The Rails framework magically creates and calls a group_ids method with the list of groups submitted with the user record. It all works great for new User records.

However, for edits, the group_ids method is called by the controller when the request parameters are applied to the model, and this immediately updates the database Membership table. If the User save fails for any reason, e.g., it doesn't pass validation, the User fields are rolled back, but the changes to Memberships persist. The solution seems call for a transaction. Using transactions inside the controller is discouraged though, and since the Rails framework is automatically calling group_ids, I don't know where else to put it. Is there a best practice for this case?

Comment: Read this excellent article on this subject http://robots.thoughtbot.com/pneumatic-cylinders

Comment: Cool! That solves the problem of updating with no group checkboxes checked in a somewhat different way than the article I linked to solved it. That's not actually my question though. Let's say "no groups" is an invalid case. The user save fails, but the groups are still deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's totally ok to use transactions in controllres. 
It's discouraged having too much logic in a controller. Get it running first and then 
extract it somewhere else, if you controller actiion is doing to much stuff.

> I don't know where else to put it. Is there a best practice for this case?

Yes, put it in a model object, this is the place where buiseness logic should leave. And do not get braindamaged by Rails. Models are not only ActiveRecords, but everything, which is not 
a View or Controller.

See [7 Patterns to Refactor Fat ActiveRecord Models](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)

However you could also go without a transaction by mass assigning the user attributes first and then, if that succeeded, assign the group_ids

```
group_ids = params[:user].extract! 'group_ids' || []
user.update_attributes(group_ids) if user.update_attributes(params[:user] || {})
```

This is going to work in 99% of cases, it's less secure as having a transaction, because it's still possible, that user attributes get updated, but the group assignment fails in case of a network error between the db and the rails app for example.

IMHO it's totally ok if only one of the both steps succeeds. Somebody wanted to change the user data and assign the user to some new groups at one time. Group assignment was fine, so let's persist it. The profile was wrong, let's show an error for that, but why should the group assingment be repeated? That would be even less user friendly.

Comment: OK, I'll put the transaction in the controller then. I'm starting to think though that the group_ids method is just badly implemented. It's making database calls that shouldn't be made until User.save. Having a transaction is just a kludgey workaround to that bug. I want to apply the group membership values to the model class, just as I want to apply simple fields like user name. I just don't want to persist to the database until the full record is valid. Rails isn't making that easy.